# How to Show User Fields in one to one Model in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I create a project with Laravel nova
I create Doctor model and resource
User and Doctor has one to one relation

**User Model:**

```
public function doctor(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Doctor::class);
}
```

**Doctor Model:**

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now I want to fill user fields from Doctor resource:

**Doctor resource:**

```
public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        
        Text::make('User Name', 'user.name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

        Text::make('User Email', 'user.email')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'email', 'max:254')
            ->creationRules('unique:users,email')
            ->updateRules('unique:users,email,{{resourceId}}'),

        Password::make('User Password', 'user.password')
            ->onlyOnForms()
            ->creationRules('required', Rules\Password::defaults())
            ->updateRules('nullable', Rules\Password::defaults()),

        Text::make('First Name', 'first_name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

        Text::make('Last Name', 'last_name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),
```

In this Doctor fields:

`first_name` and `last_name` are in `doctors` table but user name, email and password are in `users` table

when I create new doctor it show

> The User Name field is required.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use use Relation Fields
In Doctore Resource you have to call User Fields

```php
 //... doctor fields
 Text::make('First Name', 'first_name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

 Text::make('Last Name', 'last_name')
         ->sortable()
         ->rules('required', 'max:255')
  ];
  
  // User Fields
  BelongsTo::make('User')->fields(new UsersFields)
```

```php
Then create App\Nova\UsersFields.php
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;

class UsersFields
{
    public function __invoke($request, $relatedModel)
    {
        return [
            Text::make('User Name', 'name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

        Text::make('User Email', 'email')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'email', 'max:254')
            ->creationRules('unique:users,email')
            ->updateRules('unique:users,email,{{resourceId}}'),

        Password::make('User Password', 'password')
            ->onlyOnForms()
            ->creationRules('required', Rules\Password::defaults())
            ->updateRules('nullable', Rules\Password::defaults()),

    }
}
```

You may also find more details in doc [Nova Relations](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/relationships.html)